# Valgrind error: conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) - C

Tags: c, arrays, valgrind

I am trying to write a program that receives messages and reads them. Based on what those messages are it then prints out some text. As that is the part of the code that valgrind is warning me about, I left it there for you to see. As far as I read online, there is supposed to be an initialization problem but I do not know where.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int oprimek = 0;
    char name[] = "/cmdQueue";
    char msg[255];
    msg[256]='\0';
    char submsg1[5];
    submsg1[6]='\0';
    char submsg2[250];
    submsg2[251]='\0';
    int len=0;
    int x=0;
    struct mq_attr atr;
    atr.mq_maxmsg = 5; 
    atr.mq_msgsize = 255;
    oprimek = mq_open(name,O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL,0660, &atr);
    if(oprimek == -1){
        perror("error");
        mq_unlink(name);
        return -1;
    }
    time_t sek;
    int size=0;
    while(1){
    mq_getattr(oprimek,&atr); 
    if(atr.mq_curmsgs>0){
        size=mq_receive(oprimek, msg, atr.mq_msgsize,0);
        if(size==0){
            printf("Length is 0.");
        }else{
            len=strlen(msg);
            msg[len]='\0';
            strncpy(submsg1,msg,5);
            submsg1[5]='\0';
            if(strcmp(msg, "datum")==0){
                time(&sek);
                printf("%s", ctime(&sek));
            }
            else if(strcmp(submsg1,"izpis")==0){
                x=0;
                while(x<len){
                    submsg2[x]=msg[5+x+1];
                    x++;
                }
                printf("%s\n",submsg2);
            }
            else if(strcmp(msg,"zakljuci")==0){
                printf("Turning off!\n");
                return 1;
            }
            else{
                printf("Unknown message: %s \n",msg);
            }
        }
    }   
    }
    mq_close(oprimek);
    mq_unlink(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should really check your array boundaries. You are writing outside them on multiple locations. For example `char msg[255];
    msg[256]='\0';`. You've defined an array with 255 elements, the first begin msg[0], and the last being msg[254]. Meanwhile you are assigning a value to msg[256], which is outside the array boundaries. This could either cause a segmentation fault, where you are writing to memory not assigned for your program. or it could write to other memory assigned for your program, which could cause undefined behavior.

Comment: This code `len=strlen(msg); msg[len]='\0';` is futile, since `strlen` cannot work without the required  string terminator at that position anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your help.I fixed the arrays, yet the error is still here.

Comment: How does the valgrind output look? What options are you running valgrind with? What compiler and flags are you using?

If you are using gcc, make sure to use the -g flag when compiling. This enables valgrind to give more informative output, such as line numbering. 

Also, you could try and use the --leak-check=full and --track-origins=yes options for valgrind. They might give you something to work with.

But if you can, post the valgrind output in the answer.

Comment: I tried adding a picture but i could not. Full error: ==14387==Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) ==14387== at 0x$C#=F/(:strlen(in/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)==14387== by 0x400AD: main (in (home/katja/Documents/prejemnik/make/main)==14387. and i am using a makefile in which I did include -g flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by writing

```
memset(msg,0,sizeof(msg))
```

right under the declaration.

Comment: You should put your answer as accepted answer, so that people know that the question is solved. :)

Answer (score 5):

The bigger problem, as I see it is with

```
 msg[256]='\0';
 submsg1[6]='\0';
 submsg2[251]='\0';
```

whereas you defined the arrays to be of length `255`, `5` and `250`, respectively. The valid access is for index `0` to *size-1*.

Here, you're accessing out of bound memory which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Nothing is guaranteed once you hit UB.

Comment: same with `char submsg2[250];
    submsg2[251]='\0';` and `char msg[255];
    msg[256]='\0';` as well.

Comment: @LudvigRydahl Right, updated, though the attempt was to get the idea across. :)

Comment: I did as you suggested, but the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the errors pointed out by others:

if(atr.mq_curmsgs>0)

the above code will cause valgrind to complain about a conditional jump on an uninitialized value since you have not assigned a value to atr.mq_curmsgs, unless it is done in the call to mq_getattr(oprimek,&atr).

Comment: I call mq_getattr one line before the if. Is that not enough? how shouoldI write it instead?